# Soundcloud API play event fired but not counted

Tags: soundcloud

I'm using a standard Soundcloud widget to run an embed song playback in our ads unit:

```
var scWidget = SC.Widget(scPlayer);
var songClicked = false;
scWidget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
    scWidget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function() {
        if(!songClicked){
            AdvertEvents.counter('Song Play');
            songClicked = true; // make sure only count one play per load
        }
    });
});
```

Basically I'm adding a play count tracker to our system whenever the song starts playing using the Events.PLAY event. This should be equal to or fewer than the playcount on Soundcloud. But the 'Song Play' counter in my system appears to be higher than actual play count on Soundcloud (5k 'Song Play' events recorded in our system vs 3k playcounts on Soundcloud). What could be the problem here? Doesn't the PLAY event mean the song should be counted as one play on Soundcloud? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure the PLAY event triggers the play count on SC.

Comment: No it doesn't. But it does mean that my visitor clicked on the embedded Play button and the song started playing, which means the the play count on SC should also increase by 1.

Comment: The embedded SC Players triggers the +1 on the SC count, but the API doesn't.

Comment: Yep that's what I meant. I used the embed SC player. When I tested by clicking on the play button of the embed player, the song started playing, my system logged as +1 playcount, and on Soundcloud the playcount + 1 too (I checked by refreshing the song page, the number actually went up by 1). But for some reason the actual number on my system appeared to be large than on SC, not the other way round.

Comment: You have to test when SC hit the +1 playcount, maybe they are blocking the +1 from the same source within x time, or something like that. Or maybe you have to listen x minutes before hit the +1 on SC, but your count is increased at the play click instead.